# question on create new instance of ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

if I have a ActiveRecord model:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
end
```

In, Database, the Car table has columns "store_id".

Now, I would like to create a car instance and save to DB,(suppose there is a store instance called "STORE_INSTANCE"), should I use:

```
car1=Car.new({:store=>STORE_INSTANCE})
```

or

```
car1=Car.new({:store_id=>STORE_INSTANCE.id})
```

Which one is correct? or both are OK??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both are ok if you STORE_INSTANCE is already saved and persist in you database.